# executing a remote cgi script with PhP

Tags: php, email, cgi

I have a url/cgi script that displays data and graphs about my server.

[image: mailgraph output]

But I would like to display the output within the session on another server.

How do I access a remote cgi script in PhP?

Comment: You need to use cURL or something similar to login to `http://zippy-mail.com/index.php?p=mportal` and store the cookie. Then, you can access mailgraph.cgi. Also, if the cookie expires, you need to re-authenticate. If you happen to own zippy-mail.com, you can just create a secret backdoor for your other servers (like it checks if the server's IP is in its whitelist, and if it is, let it view the mailgraph.cgi).

Comment: @DaveChen  yes, I manage the server and I have a passwordless tunnel to the device if needed.

Comment: Sweet, this makes it much easier. Just do a simple `file_get_contents` on mailgraph.cgi. Then, go to your zippy-mail website and allow the server's IP to access mailgraph.cgi regardless of authentication.

Comment: @DaveChen  It doesn't like the ip address ->  Warning: file_get_contents(107.191.60.48:/usr/local/mailman/cgi-bin/mailgraph.cgi): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in

Comment: Try using the direct link, or at least prepend `http://` to your IP link.

Comment: @DaveChen   really close.  The images don't come in though  http://i.imgur.com/bBEIJAd.png

Comment: I got it by hacking the name section of the cgi script.

Comment: I was going to suggest putting the cgi script in an iframe because it is only displaying data, and having it feed through a proxy was overkill. Glad you could get it anyways. :D